# MAMPのphpMyAdminのユーザー名・パスワードが消えた

Tags: phpmyadmin

MAMPをインストールし、よくわかりもせず、データベースやファイルなどを好き勝手いじってしまったせいで、phpMyAdminにログインできなくなってしまいました。

`http://localhost/MAMP/?language=Japanese`

上記のURLにアクセスすると、MySQLのユーザー名・パスワードが表示されず、以下のようになってしまっています。

[image: mamp]

MAMPやMySQLやphpMyAdminは初期化しても問題ないので、対処法を教えて欲しいです。

Answer (score -1):

MAMPをuninstallしてから再度インストールするのが良いかと思います。

Comment: MAMPをアンインストールすると、ユーザー名・パスワードが表示されるようになりましたが、今度はphpMyAdminのログインページが表示されなくなってしまいました。

Comment: http://localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=Japanese
こちらのページからのphpMyAdminのリンクがなぜか消えていましたが、URLを直打ちすることでログインは可能になりました。ありがとうございます。